# How run my application in background in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background

I want to know how to run my  application background in iphone ?

Comment: What do you want your application to do in the background?

Comment: Recognizing call events using core telephony.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Background processing is available for certain specific purposes. I'm not sure that yours is one of the allowed background tasks, but you can read about it in the *[Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `UIApplicationDelegates`

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication*)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application
```